# SQL Query have 0 instead of 'null'

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I make 'null' data represented as 0 instead of 'null'? See query below and screenshot :)

```
SELECT Supervisor,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2 THEN (case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`) end) END) `Monday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 3 THEN (case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`) end) END) `Tuesday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 4 THEN (case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`) end) END) `Wednesday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 5 THEN (case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`) end) END) `Thursday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 6 THEN (case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`) end) END) `Friday`,
SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 7 THEN (case when employeehours.paycode = '01 Ordinary' then (employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`) end) END) `Saturday`
JOIN payroll.employeehours ON employeedatanew_copy.`ID Number` = employeehours.employeeid
WHERE employeehours.workdate BETWEEN '$staticstart' AND '$staticfinish'
GROUP BY supervisor
```

[image]

Comment: Use [`IFNULL()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

Comment: like so? does not work....
         SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2 THEN (CASE WHEN employeehours.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5' then (IFNULL(IF(`Other Rate` = 0, (employeehours.employeehours * `Base Rate`),(employeehours.employeehours * `Other Rate`)),0)) end) END) `Monday`,

Comment: got it!   IFNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(workdate) = 2 THEN (CASE WHEN employeehours.paycode = '02 Overtime 1.5' then (IF(`Other Rate` = 0, (employeehours.employeehours * `Base Rate`),(employeehours.employeehours * `Other Rate`))) end) END),0) `Monday`,

Comment: thanks heaps man, your a life saver!

Comment: Sure. `COALESCE` (which is a standard function) would've worked as well the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
COALESCE(employeehours.employeehours * `base rate`, 0)
```

Comment: this is useful to me for future but not in this case, as I am looking to get rid of the nulls, thanks anyway!